# How do I use a variable to reference another variable in Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to create a loop that sets values of a set of variables, and I want to use the incremented loop variable to define which variable I'm setting the value of, like this:

```
var box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6;
for (var i = 1; i <= 6; i++)
{ 
  //Here I want to set the value of my "boxes"
  box["i"] = i;
}
```

So in this case the result I want would be

```
box1 = 1
box2 = 2
box3 = 3
```

Etc.

I realize I could use an array in the example above, but it might come in handy in another situation.

I've read some examples on SO ([example 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5117127/javascript-dynamic-variable-name), [example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6084858/javascript-use-variable-as-object-name), [example 3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13291554/dynamic-variables-names-in-javascript)) but they rely on the `windows` property which isn't used in GAS.

Is it possible use variables in variable names?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to do that.

### Code

```
function setVariables() {
  // create variables
  var box1, box2, box3, box4, box5, box6;

  // set variables dynamically
  for(var i=1; i<=6; i++) {
    eval("box"+[i] + " = " + i);
  }

  // log variables (dynamically)
  for(var j=1; j<=6; j++) {
    Logger.log(eval("box"+[j]));
  }
}
```

### Screenshot

[image]
<sub>(Didn't add the first logger in the example code because it spoils the result)</sub>

### Reference

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/5613865/1536038
- chapter 4.12, p79, "JavaScript, The Definitive Guide, 6th edition", David Flanagan
- [Mozilla Foundation: eval()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/eval)

Comment: Thanks! Works the way I need!
I'm curious though, I read the documentation from Mozilla you linked and one part is about when _not_ to use `eval`. One subsection to that is "Accessing member properties". But maybe this isn't really properties?

Comment: @Punchlinern See chat: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13056/conversation/eval

Comment: Yeah, I read it, and responded.